# Why hostname and IP gets changed after restart of EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After restarting AWS EC2, hostname & public IP gets changed.

Remote docker clients get affected as they rely(`export DOCKER_HOST`) on these public names.

---

How to resolve this dynamic IP(public) problem of EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, AWS assigned public IP addresses as well as hostnames are ephemeral, meaning they will be released back to the pool if you restart the instance. If you really need a persistent IP address, you can use [Elastic IPs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html), but bear in mind there’s a limit per region.

Note: I’d still recommend evaluating the need for using a public IP from the IPv4 pool, as they are a rare resource. Most of the times, one can get by well by using the correct combination of security groups and private IPs, along with [Route53 hosted zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-working-with.html) for friendly naming, assuming instances are in the same VPC or can communicate via VPC peering.

Comment: Docker clients are outside vpc

Comment: @overexchange its not your docker client problem, it is the public IP of AWS resources being changed on restart.

Comment: The answer still applies. If you really need a public IP that won’t change between restarts, you need to setup an Elastic IP and attach it to your EC2 instance.